# How to get a progID from the ROT?

Tags: c#, excel, com, interop

**Introduction:**

I'm trying to iterate through the ROT (Running Object Table) and search for a specific `progID` of a COM object. In my case, the `progID` should be `Excel.Application`.

For example, if i have a single instance running of excel, i get the `Excel.Application` like this:

```
Excel.Application excel = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

---

**The Problem:**

If i have more than one instance running, this call give me basically *any* instance, and i'm not able to identify the right instance (For example by the window title, ...). So, i need a specific instance which is identifyable by it's open `Workbook` or it's window title.

---

**Current approach:**

Since `Marshal.GetActiveObject` want a progID, i tried to go through the ROT and look for all progID's, which are currently existing:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (GetRunningObjectTable(0, out IRunningObjectTable pprot) == 0)
    {
        pprot.EnumRunning(out IEnumMoniker ppenumMoniker);
        ppenumMoniker.Reset();

        var moniker = new IMoniker[1];

        while (ppenumMoniker.Next(1, moniker, IntPtr.Zero) == 0)
        {
            CreateBindCtx(0, out IBindCtx ppbc);
            pprot.GetObject(moniker[0], out object ppunkObject);

            moniker[0].GetDisplayName(ppbc, null, out string ppszDisplayName);
            moniker[0].GetClassID(out Guid pClassID);

            ProgIDFromCLSID(ref pClassID, out string lplpszProgID);
        }
    }

    // Excel excel = (Excel)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"); 
}
```

I noticed the following things:

- The call `ProgIDFromCLSID()` gives me `file` or `null` everytime.
- I can't identify the correct `Type` with `GetType()` from `ppunkObject`.
- `ppszDisplayName` gives me sometimes the path of a excel document, sometimes the title of the current open workbook.

---

**The Questions:**

- Is there a way to identify the right COM object with this approach? If no,
- Is it possible **in general** to get the right `progID` from the ROT?

Also, please let me know if there is an easier way to identify my instances.

---

**Additional Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
```

and

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
private static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, out IRunningObjectTable pprot);

[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
private static extern void CreateBindCtx(int reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);

[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
private static extern int ProgIDFromCLSID([In] ref Guid clsid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string lplpszProgID);
```

---

Comment: So you know the exact path to the Excel file, or are there more instances of one file present? Or in other words, you search for the instance of a specific Excel file?

Comment: No, i don't have the exact path where the file is, since the path is generated automatically (and the name too) from a 3rd party application. Basically, the workbooks are different.

Comment: @xMRi In other words, i search for a specific instance of a excel by it's caption, since there is one string which is unique (and i got this string).

Comment: AFAIK there is only a Moniker for the filename. I never saw something else and I use it only with filenames. Maybe it is easier to enumerate all instances of open Excel files (see extensions of the filename) and then to enumerate all internal workbooks it holds.

Comment: You want it "identifyable by it's open Workbook or it's window title" but then say you can't know the document name because a 3rd party app generates it.  This isn't going to work, you must know the name to use the ROT.  Roman wrote a pretty decent substitute for the irotview utility, have a look-see to find back anything recognizable. http://alax.info/blog/1444

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the hint, got a solution now. Thought yesterday the path may different, but basically the folder is in AppData everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

It seems there is no way to obtain the proper `progID` from the ROT (and it wouldn't help, since `Excel.Application` for example doesn't give a specific instance). However, it is possible, if you know, where the file will be stored (A part of the path seems to be enough).

---

**Full Code (Working Example):**

```
// Microsoft.CSharp, 4.0.30319
// Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, 15.0.4420.1017

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;



public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object ppunk = null;

    if (GetRunningObjectTable(0, out IRunningObjectTable pprot) == 0)
    {
        pprot.EnumRunning(out IEnumMoniker ppenumMoniker);
        ppenumMoniker.Reset();

        var moniker = new IMoniker[1];

        while (ppenumMoniker.Next(1, moniker, IntPtr.Zero) == 0)
        {
            CreateBindCtx(0, out IBindCtx ppbc);

            moniker[0].GetDisplayName(ppbc, null, out string ppszDisplayName);

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ppbc);

            // Identify by worksheet path
            if (ppszDisplayName.ToLower().Contains(".xls") && ppszDisplayName.ToLower().Contains("appdata"))
            {
                pprot.GetObject(moniker[0], out object ppunkObject);
                ppunk = ppunkObject;
            }
        }
    }

    if (ppunk != null)
    {
        Excel.Workbook workbook = ppunk as Excel.Workbook;
        Excel.Application excel = workbook.Application;

        // Do something
        dynamic title = workbook.FullName;

        excel.Quit();
    }
}



// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684004(v=vs.85).aspx
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
private static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, out IRunningObjectTable pprot);

// https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms678542(v=vs.85).aspx
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
private static extern void CreateBindCtx(int reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);
```

---

Much text, short sense: Basically this snippet give you the Excel COM object, if you know only a part of the path or the filename of the workbook.

Comment: Just keep in mind that AppData is not exactly very unique, given it is the folder in which all programs ought to store their non-public files.

Comment: @HansPassant In the example it's for reference only, in my case it is something like `..\AppData\UniqueSubFolder\*\*\*.xlsm`.